# An env. variable isn't nil, but in ruby it's nil:

Tags: ruby, linux, environment-variables

An env. variable isn't nil, but in ruby it's nil:

```
my_comp% irb
irb(main):001:0> ENV["my_var123"]
=> nil

my_comp% echo $my_var123
some_value:fdsfdsfdsfds
```

Why?

Comment: Is it an `export`? `export my_var123; irb`

Comment: @Ryan if it wasn't, how would it be visible via `echo $my_var123`?

Comment: @Jily it's a shell variable, but not an environment variable.

Comment: Are you 1000% sure that it's an environment variable and not some other kind of variable, like a shell variable, or a local variable (if your shell supports such a thing)? What test did you use to determine that it is an environment variable and not some other kind of variable? What shell are you using? What kinds of variables does your shell have?

Answer (score 1):

`echo $my_var123` check has nothing to do with the current environment:

```
$ foo=bar
$ echo $foo
#⇒ bar
$ env|grep foo
$
```

And `ENV` in ruby derives *the current shell environment*. To update the environment, one uses `export`:

```
$ export foo=bar
$ echo $foo
#⇒ bar
$ env|grep foo
#⇒ foo=bar
```

Comment: but in /etc/environment all the variables are without export and they're all visible.

Comment: So what? On login, during the activation of the PAM stack, `pam_env.so` reads `/etc/environment` and _updates the environment_.

Comment: then why call "export" in /etc/environment?